# Access Database Adapter in Zend Framework 2 from a Model

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

i am new to Zf2, and i want to know how can i access the database Adapter in Zend Framework 2 from a Model ?
If i am working inside a model, and i want to fetch the db adapter ?
how ?

i tried

```
use Zend\Db;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

$dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$adapter = new Adapter();
```

but does not work !
I will be glad if you give me some examples .

Tarek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the service locator from models that way. And you do not need to for that purpose. If your module.php setup of the current model is correct then use:

> $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();